# Vertical alignment of fonts of different size on same line in ConTeXt

Tags: vertical-alignment, context

Given a document like this

```
\starttext
\setupbodyfont[palatino,8pt] small
\setupbodyfont[palatino,12pt] normal
\setupbodyfont[palatino,16pt] big
\stoptext
```

how would I center those words vertically?

Comment: If you intend to present these elements on a separate page, then a [makeup](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Makeup#Vertical_Aligment) would be the obvious approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want to achieve. One way is to use `\framed[location=lohi]`. For example

```
\defineframed
  [vcentered]
  [
    location=lohi,
    frame=off,
  ]

\starttext
\dontleavehmode
\vcentered[foregroundstyle={\switchtobodyfont[palatino,8pt]}]{small}
\vcentered[foregroundstyle={\switchtobodyfont[palatino,12pt]}]{normal}
\vcentered[foregroundstyle={\switchtobodyfont[palatino,16pt]}]{big}
\stoptext
```

[image]